# android: no view found for id for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment, fragmentmanager

I'm sorry for posting a question on the subject again but this is driving me crazy.

I have a fragment and I'm adding views programmatically to a LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/items_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"/>

val items =buildView1(event) +buildView2(event) +buildCrew(event) 
items.forEach {dataBinding.itemsContainer.addView(it)}
```

crew is a fragments, so I add it like this:

```
private fun buildCrew(event: Event): List<View> {
        return listOf(
            FrameLayout(requireContext()).apply {
                id = View.generateViewId()
                val transaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                val f = CrewFragment()
                transaction.add(id, f)
                transaction.commit()
        })
    }
```

it works but navigating away from this page and coming back results in the error:

```
No view found for id 0x1 (unknown) for fragment CrewFragment{92ba272}
```

I also tried to create a custom view with a FragmentContainerView:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/event_detail_crew"
        android:name="redacted.package.CrewFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

this solves the error but causes two problems:

- the fragment seemed to be attached using the activity's fragment manager, I need the containing fragment's `childFragmentManager` as the two need to share a `viewModel` with

  private val viewModel: CrewViewModel by lazy {
  requireParentFragment().getViewModel()
  }
- when navigating away and coming back the contents of `CrewFragment` are not visible anymore, none of `CrewFragment`'s lifecycle methods are called

What is going on here?

Comment: Try setting an id on the `FrameLayout` you are creating inside the fragment? random guess :-)

Comment: @Blundell that's what the first line in the apply{} block is for

Comment: oh yeah sorry. Using the same ID for the view and the fragment confused me :)

Comment: I will not question why you use `ListView` instead of `Recyclerview`, but from your log the error should be located in `CrewFragment.onCreate()`: CrewFragment has no view attached

Comment: @longi I'm not using `ListView`, I'm creating a `LinearLayout` views in it. The reason I'm not using a `RecyclerView` are two: I don't need recycling as the views are all different, managing Fragments in it is complicated. `CrewFragment.onCreate()` should not have any problem as it is used in other parts of the app and also works using `FragmentContainerView`. The error says that android can't find a view with id 1 to re-attach the fragment to when coming back, which is weird because the view should be still there as the parent's fragment `onViewDestroyed` is not being called

Comment: just for the fun, try to set `retainInstance` in your fragment to `true`. The value is deprecated nowadays, however,  it resolved some similar issues with recreation for me in the past. If your problem is should be solved with this, you could have something to dig deeper?! Happy coding

Comment: @longi been there, done that. on both the child and the parent, to no avail. I think the problem is that android is trying to restore the views but can't find the view to attach the fragment to because is has been added programmatically. thanks for the suggestion tho

Comment: you are returning list 'buildCrew(event: Event): List<View>' instead of a single view.. Does this work fine?

Comment: @SohaibAhmed the views returned with the list are then added to  LinearLayout, I need this because some other build methods need to return more than one view (you can see this in thefirst block of code). I tried to return a signle view but the issue persist.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm currently facing similar issue.

Comment: no, I had to rethink the whole thing to use FragmentContainerView directly in the parent fragment and let android do its s**t the way it likes it. The goal was to have a dynamic order of the various elements, now I have multiple instances of the same fragment attached and they get hidden based on the order I need to achieve. is ugly but it's the only solution at the moment